# Contact form 7 Wordpress: Trying to make a dropdown menu to trigger an alert

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, contact-form-7

I am created a contact form in Wordpress, using Contact form 7 - plugin.

Is it possible to create a dropdown-menu, in which, an action is triggered when the user selects one of the options from the menu? e.g. displays an alert saying something like "great choice"?

Comment: this can be done using jQuery... Ill have a go and post something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here so we select your dropdown menu, we then create a event handler to watch for the user to click on there and then we simply use alert

```
$('.YourDropDownClass').click( function(){
    alert('Great Choice!');
});
```

Some tools for you to learn JQuery:

http://jquery.com/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/